# Problema con la ventana de Tkinter en mac al momento de ejecutarla

Tags: tkinter, vscode, macos

Tengo un problema que creo es con la configuración de algo que impide ver el programa de python. El problema esta en mac, porque he probado el mismo codigo en windows y me funciona. Uso vscode para ejecutar el programa, tambien lo intente desde la terminal pero ocurrua el mismo error
Al momento de ejecutar cualquier programa es como si no funcionaran las ventanas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se logra ver el programa si juego con las opciones del menu de arriba
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El texto que hay botton se ve pero cada que muevo el mouse cambia de color y no logre hacer que estuviera en las capturas

Les dejo el codigo si quieren pero no creo que sea el problema ya que en windows si funciona

```
from tkinter import *

vent = Tk()
vent.title("Suma")
vent.geometry("700x400")


def fSuma():
    n1=txtNum1.get()
    n2=txtNum2.get()
    r=float(n1)+float(n2)
    txtNum3.delete(0,'end')
    txtNum3.insert(0,r)    
    

lblNum1 = Label(vent,text="Primer Número: ",bg="yellow")
txtNum1=Entry(vent,bg="pink")
lblNum2 = Label(vent,text="Segundo Número: ",bg="yellow")
txtNum2=Entry(vent,bg="pink")
btn1=Button(vent,text="Sumar", command=fSuma)
lblNum3 = Label(vent,text="Resultado: ",bg="yellow")
txtNum3=Entry(vent,bg="cyan")

lblNum1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=6, pady=6, sticky="w",ipady=6)
txtNum1.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=6, pady=6)
lblNum2.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=6, pady=6, sticky="w",ipady=6)
txtNum2.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=6, pady=6)
btn1.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=6, pady=6, ipady=4, ipadx=10)
lblNum3.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=6, pady=6, sticky="w",ipady=6)
txtNum3.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=6, pady=6)


vent.mainloop()
```

Gracias por su atención :D

Comment: Me dio el mismo error, que te sale en la terminal de VSCode? A mi me da un warning sobre que la versión de tkinter esta obsoleta. Tal vez ese sea el problema. checa las versiones igual de Python.

Comment: La terminal no me daba ningun error, la solucion fue actualizar el Tkinter con homebrew, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es la versión de Tkinter en Mac, la cual es tkinter 0.1 y en el terminal aparece una advertencia de que no la uses porque esta obsoleta.

Utilizando homebrew puedes instalar la ultima version que este disponible, la cual debería de resolver el error (creo que es la forma más fácil porque no necesitas importar las variables), acá puedes verlo [python-tk@3.11 - Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/python-tk@3.11), por último, anexo las pruebas de que si funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]